# How to add a custom view inside list view in SugarCRM?

Tags: sugarcrm

I make a custom view using this http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.8/User_Interface/Layouts/Creating_Layouts/. What I want to do now is to use the custom view into the listview of a module (e.g. Accounts). What should I do to make that?

Comment: Anyone knows the answer for this question?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You talk about views, but link layouts.

If you want to customize the list layout of Accounts you want to create/modify one or more files of
custom/modules/Accounts/clients/base/layouts/list/list.js
custom/modules/Accounts/clients/base/layouts/list/list.php
and do a [quick repair & rebuild]

Maybe explain what you want to do and post your code :)

Comment: I already did this thing. but thanks for your response and your answer is correct

Comment: @lanceadriannedelacruz If you solved your problem it might be helpful to others if you post an answer here.